# Android beam and S beam

Tags: android, nfc, android-bluetooth, wifi-direct, android-beam

I know that S-beam uses Wifi-Direct to transfer large files but I want to know if there is a way to send files using Wifi-Direct in devices that only supports android beam (eg. Nexus 7) without any support for S-beam ?
Currently as per my knowledge android beam uses **only Bluetooth** for transfer of large files.
Basically I would like my app to give user an option to **select the mode of transfer(either Bluetooth or Wifi-Direct)** while sending a file **using android beam**.

Comment: Please post the code for whatever you have tried till now. Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before asking any question.

Comment: Sorry for earlier comment. This is what I actually had to say.I have developed a demo project to send some files using android beam by going through the documentation on http://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/index.html. But this method always use Bluetooth to transfer file. But my requirement is to send it using Wifi-Direct and in my research I found out it is possible with S-beam but my device doesn't support S-beam. So is it possible to do it in devices with just android beam?